# Very simple Welcome page/menu vs functionality

Tags: web-app, intranet

I am writing a small intranet web app for ticket managing. Most users will only be able to create new tickets and search/consult tickets previously created by themselves.

The question I have is **what to do with the welcome page?** I am personally for - having one in each web app, but in this case it will be extremely simple, with just two links.

I see an optional approach, redirecting the users directly to the search form and adding a `New ticket` button there. It would be faster and it would avoid the welcome-page-awkwardness, but it might be more confusing. Also - as the superusers will have more available options, they will probably end up having one welcome page for them, so the design would not be as consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first question would be - why do you want to give the users a welcome page? Is it to give them context or some introduction/guidance/help?

On that assumption how about the following:

Design the first page after they have logged in to be the summary view of open and/or past tickets. But - the first time they log in or if there are no tickets have the blank space fill with a contextual 'help' or welcome message perhaps wrapped in a different colour to the rest of the page to indicate some importance.

That way you treat the 'welcome page' as contextual. Once the user then creates a ticket they could always access the 'help' message through some form of a menu. This same menu could have the advanced users' options link in it.

Comment: Principally the issue is context info ("hey, you are in the maintenance app, not in accounting"). Some help is always useful, though in this case the app is so simple that it will be minimal (but there will be some, we have some computer-handicapped users). Also, my thought was that (in case of no welcome), sending the user to one page (search / create) and having them look for the button that redirects to the page they really want in a page with lots of other controls might not be optimal.

Answer (score 3):

It is good to have a Users summary page with total number of tickets pending, resolved and with a create / search box with the same page. So that user will not lost or reduce redundancy in creating duplicate ticket and status on the already created ticket.